# Rest Client Post error

Tags: ruby, post

When running the code below to post upload my argument file i get the error message below. I cannot figure this one out any help is greatly appreciated.

Error:

```
uploadhttp.rb:11:in `size': No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_size - hfs.exe (Errno::ENOENT) from uploadhttp.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Code:

```
begin
  RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :post, :url =>
 'http://my external ip:8080/upload/', :timeout => 30, :open_timeout => 30,
 :name_of_file_param => File.new("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\#{nfile}"))
  filesize=(File.size("#{nfile}"))
  result=(filesize.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/, '\\1,').reverse)
  print "#{result} bytes were uploaded to Mikez http file Server"

  rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse => err
  puts "an error has occured potential timeout"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file size should be like this

```
filesize=(File.size("C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\#{nfile}"))
```